# I want to scrape the data but this line is showing syntax error. How will I remove this error?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a"))
```

**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Answer (score 0):

There a double quotes in `[@id="content"]`, replace with single quote

```
product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a")))
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help! But another error appeared in the same line. How will I remove this error?
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: have u defined `i` ? I have modify bit my answer, please try again with new code

Comment: I've defined `i` and even after the modification, but same error appears .
**# Scraping each product's urls | 16,064 products
for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = r"C:\Users\dell\Downloads\edgedriver_win32\msedgedriver.exe")
    for i in range(1, 65):
        product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a"))
        product_urls.append(product.get_attribute('href'))**

Comment: I got the issue there was parentheses mismatching in the syntax,  corrected it, please try again